# Слова перевертыши

Tags: c, строки

Нужно найти слова перевертыши в строки и вывести их, у меня есть код но из-за пробела в `printf("%s ", t);` после `%s` стоит пробел, чтобы вывести все слова перевертыши через пробел. Так вот, из-за этого пробела у меня ни один тест не проходит код 0 из 16.
Может нужно как-то по-другому сделать?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int check(char str[])
{
    int i, length;

    length = strlen(str);

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        if (str[i] != str[(length - 1) - i]) return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[101];
    char* t;

    gets(str);
    t = strtok(str, " ");
    printf("\n");

    while (t != NULL) {
        if (check(t) == 1) {
            printf("%s", t);

        }
        t = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
```

Comment: Ничего не понял. Так а как по условию задания надо выводить найденные слова, чтобы "тесты проходили"??? Откуда мы можем знать, что там у вас в задании сказано на эту тему? Телепатов нет.

Comment: Ну в задании так и сказано - выводить через пробел. В чем проблема тогда? Может в лишнем пробеле после последнего слова?

Comment: да, в лишнем пробеле

Comment: как сделать чтобы лишний не выводился?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я - телепат. В Вашем выводе не должно быть пробела в конце строки.

*(Зачем картинки? Неужели нельзя скопировать текст?)*

Заодно - в цикле итерируйте только до половины слова.

```
int first = 1;
...
while (t != NULL) {
    if (check(t) == 1) {
        if (!first)
          printf(" ");
        else
          first = 0;
        printf("%s", t);
    }
    t = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

Comment: @Михаил Не должно быть пробела в самом конце строки вывода.

Comment: когда я ввожу deed nun  выводится deednun (слитно все)

Comment: @Михаил Не может быть. Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.

Comment: все Спасибо, красава

Comment: Игорь можете помочь сформулировать инвариант цикла который сравнивает элементы?

Comment: @Михаил Инвариантом является факт равенства пар букв в начальной и конечной частях слова.

Comment: Появилась еще одна проблемка, нужно чтобы когда ввожу слова через несколько пробелов, чтоб выводились тоже через несколько пробелов из-за этого не все проходит 14/16

Comment: @Михаил другая проблемка - другой вопрос

Comment: это к этому же вопросу относится